# I am receiving bad request key error for my variable when it exist?

Tags: python, forms, flask, request

Here is the exact error:

> BadRequestKeyError werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad
> Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could
> not understand. KeyError: 'ux'

Here is the code that I am running:

```
@app.route('/calculate_salary', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def calculate():
        # profession = int(request.form['profession'])
        user_experience = request.form['ux']
        languages = request.form['ul']
        design_tools = request.form['designtoolz']
        dob = request.form['dob']
        fullname = request.form['fn']
        age = request.form['age']
        active_country = request.form['ac']
        current_state = request.form['cs']
        number_of_experience_years = request.form['ey']

        is_developer = False
        is_designer = False

        # if int(profession) == 1:
        #     is_developer = True
        #
        # elif int(profession) == 2:
        #     is_designer = True

        database = {
            "ux": user_experience,
            "languases": languages,
            "Date of Birth": dob,
            "fn": fullname,
            "Active Country": active_country,
            "Curret State": current_state,
            "Number of Education Years": number_of_experience_years,
            "design_tools": request.form.designtoolz
        }

        result_message = cc.calculate_expected_salarys(user_experience, database, number_of_experience_years,
                                                       is_developer, is_designer, languages,
                                                       request.form.designtoolz, dob, age, fullname, active_country, current_state)

        return render_template(result_message)
```

This is the code sample from many modules that proves that it exists
html doc 1:

```
<label>How many years experience do you have?</label><br>

<input name="ux" checked="checked" type="radio" value="1"/> Less than 1 year <br/>

<input name="ux" type="radio" value="2"/> 1-3 years <br/>

<input name="ux" type="radio" value="3"/> 3-8 years<br/>

<input name="ux" type="radio" value="4"/> 8+ years<br/>

<br/>
```

Also does request.form refer to my html code module if so `ux` is definitely there.

Answer (score 0):

In your backend code, you use the `request.form` to access a form object, whereas you don't have a form on your frontend page. You need to provide an actual form on the frontend page, and add your input fields inside of it.

So instead of just:

```html
<input name="ux" checked="checked" type="radio" value="1"/> Less than 1 year <br/>

<input name="ux" type="radio" value="2"/> 1-3 years <br/>

<input name="ux" type="radio" value="3"/> 3-8 years<br/>

<input name="ux" type="radio" value="4"/> 8+ years<br/>
```

You want to instead do:

```html
<form method='post' action="{{ url_for('calculate') }}">
   <input name="ux" checked="checked" type="radio" value="1"/> Less than 1 year <br/>

   <input name="ux" type="radio" value="2"/> 1-3 years <br/>

   <input name="ux" type="radio" value="3"/> 3-8 years<br/>

   <input name="ux" type="radio" value="4"/> 8+ years<br/>
   
   <input type='submit'> Submit 
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work

Comment: What error are you getting

Comment: BadRequestKeyError werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'ux'

Comment: I have updated the form action in my answer try changing it to that